# Filtering datagridview with date

Tags: c#, datagridview, filter

Why is my `BlotterDate/Time` column empty everytime i try to list my database. But in the database has the data.

**Code:**

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.KeyChar == (char)13)
    {
        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text))
        {
             this.record1TableAdapter.Fill(this.database1DataSet.Record1);
             record1BindingSource.DataSource = this.database1DataSet.Record1;
        }
        else
        {
             var query = from o in this.database1DataSet.Record1
                         where o.BlotterNum.ToString().Contains(textBox1.Text) || o.Complainant.Contains(textBox1.Text) || o.Respondent.ToString().Contains(textBox1.Text) || o.Subject.Contains(textBox1.Text) || o._BlotterDate/Time.ToLongTimeString().Contains(textBox1.Text) || o.Facts.ToString().Contains(textBox1.Text)
             record1BindingSource.DataSource = query.ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the result:

[Image here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dre28.png)

Comment: how do you store the date in the database ? in wich format ?

Comment: LongTime format

Comment: @EmanuelPirovano btw, i use MS Access Database.